# Having trouble testing routes with React Router/Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

So I've been trying to figure out how to write unit tests for a component of mine that conditionally renders components using React Router. My problem has been that I have never been able to get it to render anything other than the root route, no matter what I do.

To further investigate this, I put together a small piece of test code, which I'm including here:

```
it('testing', () => {
        const component = mount(
            <MemoryRouter initalEntries={ [ '/next' ] }>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/next" render={ () => <p>Next</p> } />
                    <Route path="/" exact render={ () => <p>Root</p> } />
                </Switch>
            </MemoryRouter>
        );

        console.log(component.debug());
    });
```

So, my expectation would be that this code would render `<p>Next</p>`, because I'm hitting the /next route. However, it will only ever render `<p>Root</p>`.

Comment: I'm getting it's correctly(so in `debug` there is `Next` but not `Root`). jest 23.6.0, enzyme 3.8.0, react-router 4.3.1

Comment: This question can be closed with the "typo" / "unrepro" close reason.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out I misspelled "initialEntries", and that as the whole problem.

Comment: this helped in the sole fact i had no idea there was a debug command as i was getting into testing in react